# PreferenceFragmentCompat issues

Tags: android, android-support-library, preferencefragment, preference-v7

There seems to be alot of issues using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.
I have set the `PreferenceThemeOverlay`. But however, it seems that the Titles are too big. The `EditTextPreference` tag can't understand inputType.

In general. It doesn't seem to have been solved with Android support version 23.1.

Maybe someone has a way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

experienced unexpected paddings in PreferenceFragmentCompat.

had to clear the paddings on the recyclerview:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // FIX padding
    if (getListView() != null) {
        getListView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```